# Join Lines in Notepad ++ conditionally based on line start

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a lot of newlines in multiple Notepad++ files, and I'm hoping to find a RegEx/find/replace function to do the following across many files at the same time:

Join lines (separated by `CR`|`LF`) together, unless the line starts with the characters `ISA.` If the line starts with `ISA`, it should be its own first line and the rest of the lines after it should join to its line, until the next `ISA`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks,
Sydney

Comment: This is a bit unclear, could you please provide example text and expected output? Also, did you try anything before asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `\r\n(?!ISA)` with an empty string (or perhaps a single space).

`(?!...)` is a negative lookahead and means *not followed by ...*

Comment: @user6833822 also try with `[\r\n]+` instead of `\r\n` sequence as this is not clear from your question. Better to show what regex you've tried already, text samples and expected outcome.